# Mini CMS library/framework?

Tags: .net, web-applications, content-management-system

I have a web application which needs to allow admins to create content pages.  I'd rather not re-invent the wheel here.  What I need is something like Joomla, but it doesn't have to be a full fledged CMS.  I need a framework or a library that I can use with my current web application which will present a nice interface for admin to create sections/pages, and then edit and style them just like joomla.  My web application is built on .Net 3.5 and Sql Server 2005.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I cannot stand behind this system, as I feel it has some serious performance negatives, but if performance is definitely not a problem, it has a huge amount of features.

http://www.insitecreation.com/

The plus points would be

Relatively cheap

In Active development

Simple templating engine, in pure html (just pickup you html design and drop into templates, then position content tags)

Simple to remove all styling from.

Negatives

Not good for high scale performance (not that this should be considered too bad, as you should know what you are doing for that kind of site anyway)

I only add this as an option due to the fact we have used it for small quick sites in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Osmek http://osmek.com ,its a centrally hosted system where you access your content through an api. Dont know if there is .net support, but its a revolutionizing concept to content management.